# At least one of the optional fields

Tags: rust, serde

I have some structures where all the fields are optional but at least one of them or at least a specific combination of them has to be specified. For example:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct test {
    #[serde(default)]
    a: String,
    #[serde(default)]
    b: String,
    #[serde(default)]
    c: String,
}
```

All fields are optional but at least one of `b` or `c` should be provided. What would be the recommended way to represent this kind of logic, knowing that the number of fields might be larger?

Comment: How many fields are we talking? 10? Or 100? Depending on that, the solution changes.

Comment: 10 to 20 maximum.

Comment: unclear, need full requirement, and anyway it's very close to code asking, there is no such feature in serde because no one need it. Describe your file format. xy problem

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear but I am not asking for code here. If somebody can just point me to a feature/module/crate that's good enough for me. That also why I don't give a list of requirements.

Comment: I don't think there's any real pattern or feature, IIRC the normal way to do this is to implement [a bespoke deserializer](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/939#issuecomment-305228747). Link uses `deserialize_with` on a field but you can do that at the struct level by implementing `Deserialize` itself, you can see examples and discussions of that in the following comments. An other option which is mentioned is the `TryFrom` pattern where you have an unvalidated deserialization struct, and a validation step to get to the actual struct.

Comment: @Masklinn no such feature is just a plus, what OP need is a feature that check size of the map in visit_map to validate there was at least one entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a medium-performance, medium effort solution (compared to a bespoke deserializer), I would

1. Redirect deserialzation to a `HashMap<String, String>`

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(try_from = "TestDes")]
struct Test {
    a: String,
    b: String,
    c: String,
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(transparent)]
struct TestDes(HashMap<String, String>);
```

2. Tell serde how to convert `TestDes` into `Test`

```rust
impl TryFrom<TestDes> for Test {
    type Error = &'static str;
    fn try_from(mut value: TestDes) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        if /* check whether the combination of keys you need is present */ {
            return Err("need at least one value in Test");
        }
        Ok(/*
            extract value.0 into Test here
            requires to repeat 
                x: value.0.delete("x").unwrap_or("".into()),
            for each field
        */)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=891467444bc99c2d50a3279bc8941c1a)

- If you wanted better performance, you could have a `struct TestDes` that contains all of the fields of `Test` as `Option<String>`
- If you don't want to repeat the field names of `Test`, you could generate `Test` and the `TryInto` impl (and `TestDes`, if you swich to the `Option<String>` variant) in a single macro invocation.

Comment: include all code in the answer, it's not complete to include a link with the necessary code to compile

Comment: Nah. I don't think it's necessary to include code at all, even a description of how to solve the problem is sufficient. So I'd rather show the part of the code that's relevant to the problem, and leave out the boilerplate that obstructs understanding. I think anyone with basic rust skills can write the code to convert a hash map to a struct.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

> All fields are optional but at least one of b or c should be provided.

Reading the title, my first thought was you wanted at least one of *all* optional fields to be empty. But since it's just `b` or `c`, here is what I think...

Sometimes trying to get the library (`serde` in this case) do something for you might complicate things a lot more than it would be worth it. I'd most probably just make a direct check in code with the deserialized instance. Here is an example with [`anyhow`'s macro `ensure`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/1.0.53/anyhow/macro.ensure.html):

```
let t: Test = ...; // Get a deserialized instance
ensure!(!t.b.is_empty() || !t.c.is_empty(), "Either b or c needs to be provided!");
```

I'm not saying this should always be the approach, but in many cases I think that's the most sensible (and simple) thing to do. Often when I deserialize data from JSON (or some other data format) and I need to have that data validated, I have to implement some application-specific validation anyway - stuff that cannot always be expressed in declarative style. Normally that validation would go to a single place (let's say a function). I normally rely on the library to run at least some of the validations for me (like required fields, field types, etc.), but sometimes, even if a library can be configured to do a more advanced validation, it simply isn't worth it or the end result would not be as good (for example, I might want to provide a more-meaningful error message than a default one /in case the library doesn't provide me with such an option/).

Comment: anyhow's macro name is `ensure` not `expect`.

Comment: Fixed that. The code example was correct and also the link, but I had made a mix-up in the link text. Thanks @QuestionDriven!